# How do I connect an existing sqlite database to my Visual Studio (Cocoa) project and Xcode on macOS?

Tags: xcode, macos, visual-studio, sqlite, connection

I am trying to create a desktop application for Mac on a MacBook and I am trying to connect a SQLite database to the project, but I don't know how to connect it and show the data on the data on screen.

I work in Visual Studio 2019 and the Xcode is C, not Swift.

Comment: Start by reading up on prepared statements: https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/stmt.html

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow, please go through the code of conduct stackoverflow.com/conduct , Meanwhile you can add write about what you havedone till so far to solve your problem.